# A bounded set of real-valued $1$-Lipschitz maps on a totally bounded metric space is totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I'm trying to prove this result.

> **Theorem:** Let $(E, d)$ be a totally bounded metric space, $R >0$, and $\mathcal F$ the set of all real-valued $1$-Lipschitz functions $f$ on $E$ such that $\sup_{x\in E} |f(x)| \le R$. Then $\mathcal F$ is totally bounded w.r.t. the metric of uniform convergence.

Could you have a check if my proof is fine or contains subtle logical mistakes (that I could not recognize)?

---

**My attempt:** Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and let $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in E$ be centers of open balls with radius $\varepsilon$ that cover $E$. We define a map
$$
\varphi: \mathcal F \to \mathbb R^n, f \mapsto \left (  \varepsilon \left \lfloor \frac{f(x_1)}{\varepsilon} \right \rfloor, \ldots,  \varepsilon \left \lfloor \frac{f(x_n)}{\varepsilon} \right \rfloor \right ).
$$

Clearly,
$$
|f(x_i) - (\varphi(f))_i| < \varepsilon \quad \forall f \in \mathcal F, \forall i = 1, \ldots,n.
$$

Here $(\varphi(f))_i$ is the $i$-th coordinate of the $n$-tuple $\varphi (f)$. Because
$$
|f (x)| \le R \quad \forall f \in \mathcal F, \forall x \in E,
$$
we have $\mathcal K :=\operatorname{im} (\varphi)$ is finite. There is an "inverse" $\psi:\mathcal K \to \mathcal F$ of $\varphi$ such that $\varphi \circ \psi (k) = k$. Clearly, $\mathcal C :=\operatorname{im} (\psi)$ is finite. We claim that $\mathcal C$ is a collection of centers of open balls with radius $\varepsilon$ that cover $\mathcal F$.

Fix $f \in \mathcal F$ and let $g := \psi \circ \varphi (f) \in  \mathcal C$. It follows that $\varphi (f) = \varphi (g) =: k$. For $x \in E$, we pick some $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n\}$ such that $x \in B(x_i, \varepsilon)$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
|f(x)-g(x)| &\le |f(x)-f(x_i)|  + |f(x_i)-g(x_i)|  +|g(x_i)-g(x)| \\
&\le \varepsilon + \varepsilon + |f(x_i) - k_i| + |g(x_i) - k_i| \\
&\le 2 \varepsilon + \varepsilon + \varepsilon \\
&=4 \varepsilon.  
\end{align}
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Some abstract nonsense: If you pass to the completion $X$ of $E$, which is complete and totally bounded, hence compact, then the set of Lipschitz functions from $X$ to $B = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x| \leq R\}$ is compact in $C(X, B)$ by the Arzela Ascoli theorem.